# How to set autocomplete in textbox c# windows forms

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I'm trying to automatically complete textbox, but when I try to paste some code, not working for me.

So I have one query and want when I type first char to view all list.

My query is:

```
public string GetOrdersByClientName(string clientName)
{
    return "SELECT o.order_id AS 'Номер на поръчката', o.model_name AS 'Име на модел', o.client_name AS 'Име на клиент', " +
         "o.city AS 'Град', o.phone AS 'Телефон', o.weding_date AS 'Дата на Сватбата'," +
         "w.worker_name AS 'Изработва'" +
         "FROM orders AS o " +
         "INNER JOIN workers as w " +
         "ON o.made_by_worker_id = w.worker_id " +
         $"WHERE o.client_name LIKE '%{clientName}%' " +
         "ORDER BY o.order_id DESC";
}
```

I have 2 criteria to find somethink. In the textbox1 is by name, textbox2 is by phone number.
In the button code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Моля попълнете само едно от полетата за търсене");
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        string querySelect = service.GetAllOrders();
        ShowAllOrders(querySelect);
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        string querySelect = service.GetOrdersByClientName(textBox1.Text);
        ShowAllOrders(querySelect);
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
    {
        string querySelect = service.GetOrdersByPhoneNumber(textBox2.Text);
        ShowAllOrders(querySelect);
    }
}
```

I try with some code:

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
```

I paste this in the combobox method.. but not working..

Comment: Google "Bobby Tables" and think what will happen if the user types `'; Drop table Users;--`. Or `Tim O'Reilly`. Or `fo'c'sle`. Don't use concatenation, string formatting or string interpolation to construct SQL queries. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: PS by using `'%{clientName}%'` you may force an unexpected conversion to ASCII. You won't have any conversion issues with parameterized queries. Writing `WHERE o.client_name LIKE @clientName` protects you from SQL Injection *and* conversion problems